# How do I lookup a Dataverse row by it's Unique ID

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, dataverse

I am trying to create a Power Apps formula to lookup a Dataverse row by it's unique ID.

This formula works if I look up by the name column:

```
LookUp('MyTable', Name = "My Row", Name)
```

But if I try to lookup by Unique ID, assuming that the Unique ID column is called "MyTable", as it's displayed in Dataverse:

```
LookUp('MyTable', MyTable = "477c7c4e-c8ea-ec11-bb3d-0022489447e3", Name)
```

I get an error on the equals sign saying:

> Incompatible types for comparison. These types can't be compared:
> Table, Text.

Which suggests Power Apps thinks the second MyTable is a table, not the name of the Unique ID column.

Answer (score 0):

1. Rename the Unique ID column to something different than your table name (eg. "MyID"), as it seems Power Apps thinks you mean a table when you say MyTable, not the unique ID column
2. Cast your string to a Guid type like so:

   LookUp('MyTable', MyID = GUID("477c7c4e-c8ea-ec11-bb3d-0022489447e3"), Name)